# Filtering entries based on category?

Tags: plugin-development, mysql

I want to filter data based on category, I would prefer to do this using a `join` statement, but I can't figure out how an entry is related to its category. I had the same problem with matrix field, but figured it out after hours of research, the code for this is below. A similar statement to filter based on category would be great.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'affiliates';
$criteria->limit = null;
$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
$query->join('matrixblocks matrixblocks', 'matrixblocks.ownerId = entries.id');
$mat_name = 'field_handle';
$query->join('matrixcontent_'.$mat_name.' matrixcontent_'.$mat_name, 'matrixcontent_'.$mat_name.'.elementId = matrixblocks.id');
$query->join('relations relations', 'relations.sourceId = matrixcontent_'.$mat_name.'.elementId');
$query->join('content '.$mat_name, $mat_name.'.elementId = relations.targetId');
$query->andWhere($mat_name.".title"." IN ('abc', 'def')");
```

Answer (score 14):

Craft has a pretty solid engine for relational queries, so unless what you want to do is totally outside the box, there's a good chance you can accomplish what you want by using the [`relatedTo`](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations) parameter available to the [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements). *Note that the `relatedTo` entry in the docs pertain to templates and not plugin development per se, but aside from the syntax the concept and approach will be identical in PHP.*

Here are some examples, since its not obvious to me exactly what you hope to achieve:

To pull entries related to a certain category:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry, [
    'section' => 'affiliates',
    'limit' => null,
    'relatedTo' => [
        'element' => $category, // Instance of CategoryModel, or a category ID
    ],
]);
```

To pull entries related to multiple categories:

```
...
'relatedTo' => [
    'element' => $categories, // Array of CategoryModels or category IDs
],
...
```

To pull entries related to a category, where the relation is made in a certain Categories field:

```
...
'relatedTo' => [
    'element' => $category,
    'field' => 'someCategoriesFieldHandle',
],
...
```

To pull entries related to a category, where the relation is made in a certain Categories field on the EntryModel:

```
...
'relatedTo' => [
    'targetElement' => $category,
    'field' => 'someCategoriesField',
],
...
```

To pull entries related to a category, where the relation is made in a certain Entries field on the CategoryModel:

```
...
'relatedTo' => [
    'sourceElement' => $category,
    'field' => 'someEntriesField',
],
...
```

To pull entries with multiple possible relations, where *any* of the relational parameters can be met:

```
...
'relatedTo' => ['or', [
    'targetElement' => $categories,
    'field' => 'someCategoriesField',
], [
    'targetElement' => $someOtherCategories,
    'field' => 'someOtherCategoriesField',
]],
...
```

To pull entries with multiple possible relations, where *all* of the relational parameters must be met:

```
...
'relatedTo' => ['and', [
    'targetElement' => $categories,
    'field' => 'someCategoriesField',
], [
    'targetElement' => $someOtherCategories,
    'field' => 'someOtherCategoriesField',
]],
...
```

If you edit your question to include exactly what you want to do, I might be able to give you more specific advice or examples.

Comment: would you know hot to pull entries using a sub category (level 2) slug?

Comment: This is great and super helpful. Thanks for posting. I was having problems with data overwrites because of a bad double relatedTo() in my query. Problem is now solved!